# Laptop connects to WiFi or Beaglebone at one time but not both

Tags: debian, wifi, ethernet, beagleboneblack, ubuntu-16.04

I just installed ubuntu 16.04 and was connected to the WiFi network. As soon as I connect my BeagleBone Black to the laptop the connection switches over to Wired Connection treating the Beaglebone Black as an ethernet connection and doesnt have internet access anymore as there is no WiFi. I can switch between ssh'ing into the Beaglebone Black or accessing the internet but not both. Can someone explain why this is happening and what might the solution be?

Thanks,
Roy

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that when using my Mac, I have to change internet sharing options. When enabled (and settings are right) the Mac tries to share its network to the BeagleBone Black (BBB), disabling any ssh'ing to 192.168.7.2 (you should be able to serial connect by USB or UART connector). When no internet is available on Mac (or internet sharing is off), it usually leaves BBB alone to figure out its own internet connection, which does not have one unless connected to ethernet cable.

### TRY THIS:

1. Disable internet sharing options under Internet Sharing wherever that is on your computer
2. Connect serially through USB or through the UART Debug connectors (you will need the USB to UART debug serial connector dongle and install the drivers for that to work). See my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38801785/beagleboard-black-doesnt-boot-from-microsd) for explanation on that.
3. Plug in an ethernet cable (that is connected to your router or some internet connection) to the ethernet port on BBB.
4. Type `ping google.com` on terminal to see if you are connected to internet OR type `ifconfig` to view inet address (if you don't see and address like 192.168.7.2, you know you don't have access to internet).

If all goes well you should be connected to internet!