# Beagleboard Black doesn't boot from MicroSD

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, beagleboneblack, beagleboard

So I can flash the eMMC from the BBB. However I downloaded from wget https://rcn-ee.com/rootfs/2016-06-09/flasher/BBB-eMMC-flasher-ubuntu-16.04-console-armhf-2016-06-09-2gb.img.xz the Ubuntu image and extracted and placed it on the SD card through Win32DiskImager.

I put the SD card in the sd slot and tried to boot by pressing the S2 button while I connect the board to the usb for power to my laptop. I wait for LEDs to turn on and nothing happens. It works without the SD card, but not with it. Nothing blinks, nothing when I connect via ssh. Any ideas?

Comment: What's the output on the debug UART?

Comment: do you mean output of the uart coming out on terminal when I ssh? I not sure what you mean

Comment: http://elinux.org/File:CONN_REVA5A.jpg - "Debug Serial Header". If you don't have one yet, get one of those "FTDI" or similar USB-UART adapters. They start at 2$.

Comment: Will be getting one soon. I will respond when I get it and try it out. I will keep you posted

Comment: So I was able to get the debug working. I reformatted the SD card and loaded another image onto it. Then it correctly boots up the SD card as U-boot looks for the uEnv.txt and sets up environment settings and loads the kernel. Thanks. Didn't know about the UART debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my answer was quite simple. It's best to get the UART Debug connector, see [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00SL0U3RG). That way you know when you power on the BBB, the output of U-boot is displayed on your terminal when you serial connect (putty). If it does not find the image, the U-boot will send messages to the terminal notifying you that there is no kernel image.

**Getting the UART Debug connector and connecting through serial is different than ssh'ing to the actual BBB**. The output of the BBB (when you ssh) just notifies when everything loads up and the login information to the BBB is displayed on terminal. *If your board cannot find the kernel, nothing will output, and you won't know what is wrong.* However, if you connect serially through UART debug you wont have to worry, since you get to see output and error messages from U-boot telling you what's wrong.

**NOTE**: If you screw around the U-boot, which you should NEVER do (unless it really needs an update), that is the only way I can see there being no output whatsoever from the terminal when you turn on BBB and have the UART debug connected. If you didn't screw up the U-boot, then more than likely its a faulty BBB and you should return it.

HOPE THIS ANSWER WILL HELP OTHERS!